# VS Code Extension Settings CLI

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface

I want to create an automated script for setting up VS Code.
Part of this is the installation of the extensions and configuring them as necessary.

So I was able to install the extensions via CLI, but can't find how to change the extension settings by only using the command line.

For example - I want to change Jest Runner settings. I found this on their readme:

```
Jest Runner will work out of the box, with a valid Jest config.   
If you have a custom setup use the following options to configure Jest Runner:

| Command | Description |
| --- | --- |
| jestrunner.configPath | Jest config path (relative to ${workFolder} e.g. jest-config.json) |
| jestrunner.jestPath | Absolute path to jest bin file (e.g. /usr/lib/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js) |
| jestrunner.debugOptions | Add or overwrite vscode debug configurations (only in debug mode) (e.g. `"jestrunner.debugOptions": { "args": ["--no-cache"] }`) |
| jestrunner.runOptions | Add CLI Options to the Jest Command (e.g. `"jestrunner.runOptions": ["--coverage", "--colors"]`) https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli |
| jestrunner.jestCommand | Define an alternative Jest command (e.g. for Create React App and similar abstractions) |
| jestrunner.disableCodeLens | Disable CodeLens feature
| jestrunner.codeLensSelector | CodeLens will be shown on files matching this pattern (default **/*.{test,spec}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx})
```

But don't know how to access it via cmd.

Any thoughts on how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to find a solution now.
So it turns out that the settings are actually stored in:

`<userFolder>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\Settings.json`

From there I can open up the json file and add in the commands as specified by the extension's readme.

Comment: Looks like a Windows-specific issue, then, which is not mentioned in the question. Perhaps consider adding at least a Windows tag.